# Protractor tests run slow on selenium grid which has version 2.43

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Recently i started to use protractor and we have a internal selenium grid which uses 2.43 version, there are a bunch of other clients like C# , python selenium frameworks which use the grid and all the tests run pretty fast.

But when it comes to protractor the tests take really long time and sometimes even timeout . Some say 2.45 version would make protractor tests run faster. TBH i am not totally convinced with this statement , because the **changelog**  doesn't say that 2.45 version is faster than 2.43.

Has someone else faced the same problem while running protractor tests with grid which has version 2.43 ?

Comment: Is this an angular app under test? Have you tried to debug it and identify the bottlenecks - where is the slowdown happening? Is the behavior consistent across different browsers? Thanks!

Comment: Yes the app under test is angular . If i run the same tests across saucelabs with selenium 2.43 version it is fast . I have checked only with chrome there is a significant difference in the execution time .